# Finite Fields problem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

"Given a Galois Field $(\mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$ of order 8. With an element $x \in \mathbb{F}$ we create a group $(\{x^m | m \in \mathbb{Z}\}, \cdot)$. ($x^m$ is calculated via the second operator $\cdot$ in the field, for example: $x^3 = x\cdot x\cdot x$). What is $\max_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}|\{ x^m|m \in \mathbb{Z}) \}|$?"

I don't really understand the question or know how to answer... Help please?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: How the group is created/how do I get to that max

Comment: So the group consists of all element of the field of the form $x^m$ for some integer $m$ (and for a fixed $x$).

Comment: What is the order relation  in $\mathbb{F}$ with respect to which you are asked to find a max?

Comment: Do you mean $max_{x\in \mathbb{F}}(|\{x^m\mid m\in\mathbb{Z}\}|)$?

Comment: Clément: Sorry, I edited

Comment: I am seconding Clément Guérin's guess as to what the question really was supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since the field has order $8$, it's $\mathbb{F_{2^3}}$. Now consider a fixed $x\in\mathbb{F_{2^3}}$ and look at the sequence $1,x,x^2,x^3,\cdots$. As this is a finite field, this sequences is guaranteed to be periodic. The question is: how long can this sequence be? Try looking at the Frobenius Endomorphism and see if you can learn anything about the length of the sequence based on the action of the Endomorphism on the element $x$.

Comment: Well, the x^3 doesn't belong to the series as it's converted to something else in the $\mathbb{F}_8$ field. But doesn't its value depend from the primitive polynomial we chose?

Comment: @Gloomy Why would $x^3$ be something else?

Comment: Because the Field of order 8 only has polynomials up to degree 2, doesn't it?

Comment: $x^3$ is not a polynomial, it is an element in the field. You should not mix this up with the construction of the field (which uses polynomials).

Comment: @Gloomy Tobais is right, $x$ here is just intended to be a member of the field, not a formal variable. I'll edit the post to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

As $F$ is a field of order $8$, the multiplicative group $F^\times$ is of order $7$. Unless you start with $x=0$ (which is pointless), you generate a subgroup of this group of order $7$. You should knwo that a group of order $7$ must be cyclic. What does that tell you about the answer to the porblem? (It turns out that $F^\times$ is always cyclic for finite fields, but in the problem at hand we may shortcut the argument by noting that $7$ is prime - the law of small numbers is working for us here).